# Identificar o ID que possui valor ao menos uma coluna para todas as linhas

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um data.frame com as colunas: cnpj, nome, ano, rop, des, cax, pcld.

Preciso identificar os **cnpj**  que possuem o valor **"1"** em ao menos uma das colunas **rop**, **des**, **cax** e **pcld** para todos os anos. Depois disso, identificar os que tiveram descontinuidade nos anos.

Então, como primeiro passo, pensei em transpor o data.frame, para ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
 cnpj | nome | conta | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017
 
 3243 | teste| rop   |   1  |   0  |  0    | 1
 3243 | teste| des   |   0  |   1  |  0    | 0
 3243 | teste| cax   |   0  |   0  |  1    | 0
 3243 | teste| pcld  |   0  |   0  |  0    | 0
 33333| loja | rop   |   0  |   1  |  NA   | NA 
 33333| loja | des   |   0  |   0  |  NA   | NA 
 33333| loja | cax   |   0  |   0  |  NA   | NA 
 33333| loja | pcld  |   1  |   0  |  NA   | NA
```

O cnpj "3243" seria identificado como 'certo'. Ele tem ao menos um valor "1" em todos os anos. E o cnpj "33333", que não possui dados para todos os anos seguintes a 2014, foi descontinuado, ficará com "NA" naquele ano.

Já tentei transpor de várias maneiras, mas sempre da um erro. A última tentativa:

```
library(magrittr)

dados   %>% dplyr::select(CNPJ, nome, ano, rop, des, cax, pcld) %>% 
            tidyr::pivot_longer(
                                 cols = -c('cnpj', 'nome'),
                                 names_to = 'Conta'

                                )
```

Acredito que ao transpor o data.frame, os CNPJ que foram descontinuados ficarão com valor "NA" para o ano sem informação (descontinuado), então eu faria um filtro.

Exemplo de dados:

```
structure(list(
    id = c(1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 22222,22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333,3243,3243,3243,3243), 
    name = c("empresa", "empresa", "empresa", "empresa","firma", "firma", "firma", "firma", "loja", "loja","teste","teste","teste","teste"), 
    year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014,2015,2014, 2015, 2016, 2017),
    rop = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
    des = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    cax = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    pcld = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
    row.names = c(NA,14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Não ficou claro como identifica um CNPJ que foi descontinuado.

Comment: Acredito que ao transpor o data.frame, estes CNPJ fiquem com "NA" para o ano sem informação (descontinuado), então eu faria um filtro.

Comment: Qual o critério para determinar que foi descontinuado? 0 em todas as colunas daquele ano? Seja qual for, edite a questão para detalhar melhor (ao invés de descrever mais detalhes nos comentários). Sugiro colocar um exemplo de como quer o resultado final, usando como base os dados de exemplo que postou.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta feito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que pivotar duas vezes. O `pivot_longer` para as variáveis das contas depois o `pivot_wider` para distribuir os anos.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(
  id = c(1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 22222,22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333,3243,3243,3243,3243), 
  name = c("empresa", "empresa", "empresa", "empresa","firma", "firma", "firma", "firma", "loja", "loja","teste","teste","teste","teste"), 
  year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014,2015,2014, 2015, 2016, 2017),
  rop = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
  des = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
  cax = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  pcld = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
  row.names = c(NA,14L), class = "data.frame")

df   %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(id, name, year),
    names_to = 'Conta'
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, name, Conta),
    names_from = year,
    values_fro = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 16 x 7
#>       id name    Conta `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017`
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  1111 empresa rop        1      0      0      0
#>  2  1111 empresa des        1      0      0      0
#>  3  1111 empresa cax        1      1      0      0
#>  4  1111 empresa pcld       1      0      1      0
#>  5 22222 firma   rop        1      0      1      0
#>  6 22222 firma   des        0      0      0      0
#>  7 22222 firma   cax        0      0      0      1
#>  8 22222 firma   pcld       1      0      0      0
#>  9 33333 loja    rop        0      1     NA     NA
#> 10 33333 loja    des        0      0     NA     NA
#> 11 33333 loja    cax        0      0     NA     NA
#> 12 33333 loja    pcld       1      0     NA     NA
#> 13  3243 teste   rop        1      0      0      1
#> 14  3243 teste   des        0      1      0      0
#> 15  3243 teste   cax        0      0      1      0
#> 16  3243 teste   pcld       0      0      0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>